# How to run multiple SSIS packages programmatically by C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

guy, I used this code snippet, I execute multiple SSIS packages, when the first one finished, it takes a so long time to execute the another one, but I run the script command line on the CMD, it execute quickly. So I think it's the problem of code, do you know why? This is my code below:

```
SSISHelper.ExecuteSSISPackage("/F \"C:\\Users\\v-nashi\\Documents\\visual studio 2010\\projects\\ImportExcel\\ImportExcel\\LYO_DailyLogin.dtsx\"");
SSISHelper.ExecuteSSISPackage("/F \"C:\\Users\\v-nashi\\Documents\\visual studio 2010\\projects\\ImportExcel\\ImportExcel\\LYO_COSMOS_Activities.dtsx\"");


    /// <summary>
    /// Excuete SQL Server Integration Services packages with parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="para">parameter</param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public static bool ExecutePackage(string parameter)
    {
        if (File.Exists(DTExec_Path) == false)
            throw new Exception("The file DTExec.exe is not found, or the file is not exist.");

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = DTExec_Path;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = parameter;
        // True if the shell should be used when starting the process; false if the process should be created directly
        // from the executable file.
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DTExec_Path, parameter);

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        string[] results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
        foreach (string item in results)
        {
            if (item.Contains("DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0)."))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I just want to run the SSIS package programmatically, or the better way?

Comment: If you want to run in parallel, then try to use thread. It looks like process is waiting for resources.

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be like this.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();

            string packagePath = "Path of your SSIS package";

            Package package = app.LoadPackage(packagePath, null);

            //Assign your variables here.
            Variables vars = package.Variables;
            vars["FileName"].Value = variables.FileName;



            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();

            if (results == DTSExecResult.Success)
            {
               //Do what u want after success.
            }
```

For this U have to use this `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS` library from microsoft. Try to find it in GAC or Something else site.
This is for single SSIS service in same way U can execute multiple one by one.